# SystemButton FLEXIBLE_SPACE Titanium not fully working

Tags: ios, titanium-mobile, addeventlistener

I have following a tutorial in order to develop my first app. I am using a multi platform software. Now, the code below does work only the first time around, then the done button disappears. any suggestion. of course this happens in the iphone emulator.

```
//flexible space for button bars
var flexSpace = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    systemButton:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.FLEXIBLE_SPACE
});

//done system button
var buttonDone = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    systemButton:Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.DONE,
    bottom: 0
});
//add the event listener 'click' event to our done button
buttonDone.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    tfAmount.blur();
    tfInterestRate.blur();
    interestRate = tfInterestRate.value;
    tfAmount.visible = true;
    labelAmount.visible = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

find solution

```
var toolview = Ti.UI.iOS.createToolbar({
    height : 40,
    width : '100%',
    left : 0,
    top : 0,
    items : [flexSpace, buttonDone],
    barColor : '#000000'
});
win.add(toolview);
```